# form data with Get method

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I need a form that submits data with GET method. below is the image I want it to appear on the bar. [image]

can anyone guide me on how to get the desired result? I can get the value but how to add %20 &rid=0*0?

Comment: `%20` is URL-encoding for a space, which may well be done automatically by the browser, you can soon test that. If you don't have a form field called `rid`, then you could add it as a hidden field in your form, and give it the appropriate value.

Comment: If you want to combine the first name and last name fields into a single query string parameter, you'll need an `onsubmit` listener to rewrite the form data. This would be a lot easier on the server side - you've tagged your question with PHP, so I'd strongly consider doing the combination there instead.

Comment: I could not watch the picture